# React Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `App`

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, relayjs

I'm getting that error, but I'm defining a key. Here's my `App.js` that it's complaining about.

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import AccountTable from './AccountTable';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Account list</h1>
          {this.props.viewer.accounts.edges.map(edge =>
            <AccountTable key={edge.node.id} account={edge.node} />
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
    fragments: {
        viewer: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                accounts(first: 10) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            ${AccountTable.getFragment('account')}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
    },
});
```

Comment: bob ross would be proud of your code mountains.  But really you should check the uniqueness of your edge.node.id's.

Comment: do the usual sanity checks I guess. Is the above code the 100% source of the error? are the ids actually unique? maybe you have a couple of undefineds / nulls

Comment: See if you have duplicate IDs: `console.log(this.props.viewer.accounts.edges.map(edge => edge.node.id))`

Comment: So, it turns out the edge.node object does not have an id defined at this point. I think it's because the node references another fragment. I didn't have this problem when I had accounts just spelled out inside this fragment. This showed up when I broke the account graphql stuff out into it's own fragment. Do any of you know a work around?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to correct this is to base the key off the index of the map:

```
{this.props.viewer.accounts.edges.map((edge, i) =>
    <AccountTable key={i} account={edge.node} />
)}
```

Then, you don't have to worry about how unique the value of `edge.node.id` is.  The `key` only needs to be unique in the context of all the `AccountTable` siblings.  It doesn't need to be globally unique.  So, the index works well.

However, if you have a stable id that is based off of the object, that is obviously better.

Comment: According to the react documentation: "When you don't have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort". So, I'd like to make sure there's no way to get a stable id before I do this. Any suggestions on that front, or is this just not possible because my node references a different fragment?

Comment: Well, unless you do have another id, this might be your "last resort", right?

Comment: It certainly fixes the problem. I'm going to do a bit more digging, but if I can't find a way to get the id of the object I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you use the item index as the key, it may not work in cases when the array is re-ordered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/960857

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is to extract the underlying id of relay fragment as key

```js
{this.props.viewer.accounts.edges.map((edge) =>
    edge && e.node && <AccountTable key={edge.node.__id} account={edge.node} />
)}
```